# Two variable variables in one variable

Tags: php, variables

I have a `for`-loop ($x++) within another `for`-loop ($i++) , and I want both $x AND $i to be part of a variable variable:

```
${'name'.$x.'place'.$i.''} = ...;
```

Such that I get:

- $name1place1
- $name1place2
- $name1place3
- $name2place1
- $name2place2
- $name3place1 etc. etc.

However, setting variables in the way quoted above does NOT work for me (i.e. with single quotations and *two* variable variables). I get the error "**Notice: Undefined variable** [...]".

The following works:

```
${"name$x"} = ...;
```

(using double quotations and just *one* variable variable.)

How can I set variable variables with both $x *and* $i within the variable name? Thank you!

Comment: Which PHP version? The code you provided does work on PhpFiddle.

Comment: Use an array instead, that will only be messy

Comment: You will come to hate this, use `$name[$x][$i] = ...;`

Comment: `${"name".$x."place".$i} = "test";` - _BUT_ just don't do that. Use an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using curly braces within your variable name assignment to separate `$x` from the `place`:

```
$x = 4;
$i = 5;
${"name{$x}place{$i}"} = "test";
echo $name4place5;
```

Output:

```
test
```

However it would really make a lot more sense to just use an array:

```
$name[$x][$i] = "test2";
echo $name[$x][$i];
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/LAMh0)